# ifstream gcount returns 0 on getline string overload

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I'm finding that gcount on an ifstream object after a call to

```
  getline(istream &, string &)
```

returns 0.

Is this supposed to be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `gcount()` is supposed to *return the number of characters extracted by the **last unformatted input operation** performed on the object.*

`getline()` is listed in the functions supposed to updated `gcount()`,  but it is the [member `getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) of a stream and not the [string `getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline).

In case of doubt, [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) tells it black on white: *Behaves as UnformattedInputFunction, **except that input.gcount()** is not affected.*