# How to determine how many characters `std::getline()` extracted?

Tags: c++, iostream

Let's say I read a `std::string` from `std::istream` by using [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) overload. How to determine how many characters extracted from the stream? [`std::istream::gcount()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) does not work as discussed here: [ifstream gcount returns 0 on getline string overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600797/ifstream-gcount-returns-0-on-getline-string-overload)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream s( "hello world\n" );
    std::string str;
    std::getline( s, str );
    std::cout << "extracted " << s.gcount() << " characters" << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/FUsilD)

Note, for downvoters - length of the string is not the answer, as `std::getline()` may or may not extract additional character from the stream.

Comment: Ẁhat about `std::string::size`?

Comment: @Galik what about delimiter?

Comment: Need to use both `size()` and `eof()` to reverse-engineer if `std::getline` actually swallowed a newline, or hit EOF, in order to get an accurate character count.

Comment: @Slava Yes I was just thinking about that...

Comment: It is unclear what I am asking? Really?

Comment: Some people need to learn more `C++` before downvoting questions because they don't understand them.

Comment: Is making your own custom getline an option?  One which returns how many characters it had consumed, possibly including the terminating end-of-line that were discarded.

Comment: @Eljay I think answer to this question could be useful not only for me so it is does not matter if its an option for me, so if you have viable solution with that please provide an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem the way to do this is not completely straightforward because `std::getline` may (or may not) read a terminating delimiter and in either case it will not put it in the string. So the length of the string is not enough to tell you exactly how many characters were read.

You can test `eof()` to see if the delimiter was read or not:

```
std::getline(is, line);

auto n = line.size() + !is.eof();
```

It would be nice to wrap it up in a function but how to pass back the extra information?

One way I suppose is to add the delimiter back if it was read and let the caller deal with it:

```
std::istream& getline(std::istream& is, std::string& line, char delim = '\n')
{
    if(std::getline(is, line, delim) && !is.eof())
        line.push_back(delim); // add the delimiter if it was in the stream

    return is;
}
```

But I am not sure I would always want that.

Comment: One hitch may be on platforms that use CRLF for end-of-line.

Comment: @Eljay I am trying to find precise info but, as far as I am aware, the stream subsystem should seamlessly convert multibyte `EOL` sequences into `\n` on all platforms. This means that even `gcount()` should not be able to "see" companion bytes in the `EOL` sequence unless the file is specifically opened in *binary* mode. But I am not completely sure on how all that works because I don't use `Windows` so I am trying to find more info.

Comment: Apple computers from AppleDOS up through OS 9 used CR for EOL.  CP/M computers used CRLF for EOL, and platforms that followed from that lineage (DOS, Windows, OS/2).  Unix machines, and others (e.g., AmigaOS) use LF for EOL.  I've also seen one that used NEL (`\x85`) from the C1 control code set.  IBM 3390 mainframe files are often record based with fixed lines sizes (metadata in the file entry), and have no line terminating character.

Comment: @Eljay Yes but it is the responsibility of the standard stream library to *convert* those line ending sequences behind the scenes into a simple `'\n'` on all systems. So `C++` programmers only have to care about `\n` when writing programs.

Comment: @Galik • Depending on what the OP wants with the count, it may be sufficient to provide the converted count, or it may be desired to provide the raw count.

Comment: @Eljay I know, I'm just not sure the raw count is available to **any** stream function, including `gcount()` unless the file is opened in *binary* mode. In which case you get the raw count everywhere as expected. So I think this function behaves exactly inline with the stardard library functions.